I have some issues with Authenticating using the Swagger UI after trying to change header authentication key name
I have some issues with Authenticating using the Swagger UI.
I have modified the lexik_jwt_authentication.yaml file, to extract a token from the authorization header with the name "X-Authorization" instead of "Authentication" because I was previously having problems with the frontend application interacting with the backend through Caddy.
So changing the authorization header key to "X-Authorization" helpt avoid the issue between the backend and frontend authentication.
But now on swagger ui, I cant authenticate with the token because Swagger UI still tries making a Curl request with the "Authorization" key.
I would like to know what I am doin wrong or if I just dont understand what ApiKeyAuth is supposed to be used for
and is it achievable what I am trying to do?
I have read several forum and articles and tried the following configuraitons (see nelmio_api_doc.yaml below) to chang the curl request made by Swagger UI, but unfortunaly it does not accept the changes I am trying to make:
I also tried intercepting every request with a eventSubscriber and check every request "kernel.request" for a authorization key.
and modify it. I thought this was the way to go but it seems to ignore/ not work at all, so I gave up on this idea.
Unfortunaley I am stuck, else I just have to keep switching between "X-Authorization" and "Authorization" if I just want to check something on swagger ui.
Nelmio_api_doc.yaml:
nelmio_api_doc:
    documentation:
        info:
            title: My App
            description: This is an awesome app!
            version: 1.0.0
        components:
            securitySchemes:
                # Bearer:
                #     type: http
                #     scheme: bearer
                ApiKeyAuth:
                    type: apiKey
                    in: header
                    name: X-Authorization
        security:
            - ApiKeyAuth: []
    areas: # to filter documented areas
        path_patterns:
            - ^/api(?!/doc$) # Accepts routes under /api except /api/doc

lexik_jwt_authentication.yaml:
lexik_jwt_authentication:
    secret_key: '%env(resolve:JWT_SECRET_KEY)%'
    public_key: '%env(resolve:JWT_PUBLIC_KEY)%'
    pass_phrase: '%env(JWT_PASSPHRASE)%'
    token_ttl: 36000
    # token_ttl: 3600
    # clock_skew: 0
    # allow_no_expiration: false
    api_platform:
        check_path: /api/login_check
        username_path: email
        password_path: security.credentials.password
    # encoder:
    #     service: acme_api.encoder.nixilla_jwt_encoder
# token extraction settings
    token_extractors:
    #     # look for a token as Authorization Header
        authorization_header:
            enabled: true
            prefix: Bearer
            name:   X-Authorization

Swagger UI Curl (resource) request:
curl -X 'GET' \
  'https://localhost/api/users?page=1' \
  -H 'accept: application/ld+json' \
  -H 'Authorization: xxxxxx.         <<<<<<<< key is not X-Authorization as specified in nelmio__api_doc.yaml or Apiplatform.yaml

OpenApiFactoryDecorator:
#[AsDecorator('api_platform.openapi.factory')]
class OpenApiFactoryDecorator implements OpenApiFactoryInterface
{
    public function __construct(
        private OpenApiFactoryInterface $decorated,
        // private OpenApiFactory $factory,
    )
    {}

    public function __invoke(array $context = []): OpenApi
    {
        $openApi = $this->decorated->__invoke($context);   

        $components = $openApi->getComponents()->withSecuritySchemes(
            new ArrayObject(
                [
                    'access_token' => new SecurityScheme(
                        type:         'http',
                        description:  'Value for the JWT Authorization header parameter.',
                        scheme:       'bearer'
                    )
                ]
            )
        );

        return $openApi->withComponents($components);
    }
}


With ApiPlatform v4, you can do this in config/packages/api_platform.yaml :
api_platform:
    swagger:
        api_keys:
            my_token_definition:
                name: X-Authorization
                type: header


Hi there, Thank you for you reply, I immediatly updated my Api-platoform v3.3 to v4 .
But unfortunatley it did not change the behaviour of swagger/ OpenApi  UI authentication.
It still doesnt not appear as "X-Authorization" when the curl request is being made. It still only Accepts "Authorization"
